# How to substring in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

How can I use jquery on the client side to substring "nameGorge" and remove "name" so it outputs just "Gorge"?

```
var name = "nameGorge"; //output Gorge
```

Comment: jQuery is a library written in JavaScript.  It's used on top of JavaScript.  What you are asking can be done in JavaScript without the need to use the jQuery library at all.

Comment: jQuery IS JavaScript (a JavaScript library to be exact, but JavaScript, nonetheless). That having been said, I don't think using jQuery to get a substring could ever be written any easier than it already is in straight JavaScript.

Comment: Hi. I am the future. I have built a plugin for jQuery to do substrings for vanilla JS. Please use it like `let result = $.substring(value, idx)` - We have much fun in the future! 

Answer (score 238, accepted):

No jQuery needed! Just use the substring method:

```
var gorge = name.substring(4);
```

Or if the text you want to remove isn't static:

```
var name = 'nameGorge';
var toRemove = 'name';
var gorge = name.replace(toRemove,'');
```

Comment: Sorry, didn't expect this to blow up so hard after I went to sleep. I've cleaned things up here a little. Meanwhile, somebody needs to read [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19492#19492)

Comment: Hey BoltClock: How are you doing? I was trying to prove a point in here, thanks very much.. so that means that if I am trying to revamp a code for a client, and I come here looking for an answer, and the op's marked answer is satisfactory for him.. then I cannot simply post the same question nor to give an example of my problem.. very interesting.. so my question was like how are these guys so certain that if I am running a jQuery function and inside I use .split I am refering to the native JS way or some sort of tunneling or proxy to trigger that through jQuery. Also if you read the question.

Comment: My point is that to me is working within the jQuery namespace, I really don't care much if the case is that is calling directly string.split from JS, but instead from the community I have understood that if I post that exact question, it will be marked as narrowed, as this response is more accepted than the fact that there is a jQuery.split documentation reference somewhere to me at least tells me that it should be because it's there without giving any conflict to my code and all the jQuery plugins that on the deleted pictures you were able to see... so thanks once more

Comment: @JeanPaul - jQuery has no split(). We've already been over this. Both articles you linked to previously used text() to get a vanilla JavaScript string and then called string.split(). You're just plain wrong in this case. Drop it.

Answer (score 53):

Using [`.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split). (Second version uses [`.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) and [`.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) on the Array.)

```
var result = name.split('name')[1];
var result = name.split('name').slice( 1 ).join(''); // May be a little safer
```

Using [`.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

```
var result = name.replace('name','');
```

Using [`.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) on a String.

```
var result = name.slice( 4 );
```

Comment: jquery does not support replace. This is Vanilla js

Answer (score 18):

Standard javascript will do that using the following syntax:

string.substring(from, to)

```
var name = "nameGorge";
var output = name.substring(4);
```

Read more here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp

Answer (score 9):

That's just plain JavaScript: see [`substring`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp) and [`substr`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substr.asp).

Comment: Or indeed [`slice()`](http://docs.sun.com/source/816-6408-10/string.htm#1194366). Strange JS should have so many ways to say the same thing, all subtly different. `slice()` is my preferred method as it behaves consistently with `slice()` on arrays, and allows negative start and end indexes for index-from-end.

Comment: @bobince: True, and I never remember which of `substring` and `substr` takes a length parameter and which takes an end index - I always need to look up the docs to find out.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need jquery in order to do that.

```
var placeHolder="name";
var res=name.substr(name.indexOf(placeHolder) + placeHolder.length);
```

Comment: I need to do it on the client side and I already have jquery. What are you suggesting then? Sorry for the simple question, but I'm fairly a beginner with js and jquery.

Comment: That statement would return "nameGorge" because indexOf("name") would return 0.

Answer (score 2):

```
var name = "nameGorge";
name.match(/[A-Z].*/)[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, although it relies on Javascript's inherent functionality and not the jQuery library.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substr.asp
The `substr` function will allow you to extract certain parts of the string.

Now, if you're looking for a specific string or character to use to find what part of the string to extract, you can make use of the indexOf function as well.
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_IndexOf.asp

The question is somewhat vague though; even just [link text](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) with 'name' will achieve the desired result. What's the criteria for getting your substring, exactly?

Comment: Why have you linked to PHP's `strpos` function in a question on JavaScript?

Comment: You're right, too much PHP for me today. I've edited with the appropriate JS equivalent. Thanks for catching it.

Answer (score -1):

How about the following?

```
<script charset='utf-8' type='text/javascript'>
  jQuery(function($) { var a=$; a.noConflict();
    //assumming that you are using an input text 
    //  element with the text "nameGorge"
    var itext_target = a("input[type='text']:contains('nameGorge')");
    //gives the second part of the split which is 'Gorge'
    itext_target.html().split("nameGorge")[1];
    ...
  });
</script>
```