# Trim input .val() / or div .html() with jQuery

Tags: jquery

How to trim input value to first `'n'` characters only?

e.g `input value length = 10 characters` how to trim that to first 8 characters?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to substring in jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4126762/how-to-substring-in-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) method:

```
var trimmed = input.substring(0, 8);
```