# Can't set the value of input with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

I'm trying to change the value of an input field with Javascript.
I tried everything, but nothing seems to works. I tried putting the 5 between quotation marks and using jquery. I also double-checked the array and everything.

Here is the input code:

```
<input type="number" id="id_[SOME_ID_HERE]" value="0">
```

and the loop used to update the values.

```
for (var i = 0; i < shoppingCart.length; i++) {
    var val = shoppingCart[i];
    document.getElementById("id_" + val.substring(3)).value = 5;
}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zkTud/

EDIT: Seems like it doesn't work with type="text" as well...

EDIT2: Thank you everyone who answered. My problem was actually something else.
The input was loaded from another page, and it took time and the for loop I had problem with (see above) was executed before the file was done loading.
All I did was to move the for loop as is to the callback function and it works now.

Thanks anyways!
**I really appreciate the help I'm getting in this site! :)**

Comment: `alert()` is your always friend: `alert(val.substring(3))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your call to [`substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) is returning too much of the string, so there are no elements found by `getElementById`. Change it to this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < shoppingCart.length; i++) {
    var val = shoppingCart[i];
    document.getElementById("id_" + val.substring(5)).value = 5;
}
```

Here's an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zkTud/1/).

The `substring` method (when called with one argument) returns the characters from the index specified to the end of the string. Since you are specifying index 3, you get "d_1", "d_2" etc. when actually you just want the number.

Alternatively, you could of course change the string to which you append the substring, but I think that would be more confusing to read (not immediately obvious which element will be returned):

```
document.getElementById("i" + val.substring(3)).value = 5;
```

Answer (score 2):

**demo** http://jsfiddle.net/bY4EV/6/

`sustring(3)` gives `d_1`  : [How to substring in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4126762/how-to-substring-in-jquery)

hope this helps

**code**

```
var shoppingCart = new Array();
shoppingCart[0] = "prod_1";
shoppingCart[1] = "prod_3";
shoppingCart[2] = "prod_2";

for(var i = 0; i < shoppingCart.length; i++) {
    var val = shoppingCart[i];

    $("#id_" + val.substring(5)).val("5");
}

​
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this, [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zkTud/7/) , Updated and corrected your problem.

Code:

```
var shoppingCart = new Array();
shoppingCart[0] = "prod_1";
shoppingCart[1] = "prod_3";
shoppingCart[2] = "prod_2";

for(var i = 0; i < shoppingCart.length; i++) {
    var val = shoppingCart[i];

    $("#id" + val.substring(4)).val( "5");
}
```