# how to use substr() function in jquery?

Tags: jquery

how to use substr function in this script I need  `substr(0,25);`

```
<a class="dep_buttons" href="#"> something text something text something text something text something text something text </a>

$('.dep_buttons').mouseover(function(){
    if($(this).text().length > 30) {
        $(this).stop().animate({height:"150px"},150);
    }
    $(".dep_buttons").mouseout(function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({height:"40px"},150);
    });
});
```

Comment: i suggest you to take a look at toggle()

Comment: It is not clear where you want to use this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to substring in jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4126762/how-to-substring-in-jquery)

Comment: see here how to do it: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FTQUG9V6J8LN

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Extract characters from a string:

```
var str = "Hello world!";
var res = str.substring(1,4);
```

The result of `res` will be:

```
ell
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp

```
$('.dep_buttons').mouseover(function(){
    $(this).text().substring(0,25);
    if($(this).text().length > 30) {
        $(this).stop().animate({height:"150px"},150);
    }
    $(".dep_buttons").mouseout(function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({height:"40px"},150);
    });
});
```

Comment: hey I know w3school :D

Comment: Yes @valkharitonashvili I have mentioned the URL under my answer

Comment: Please, do not refer to W3Schools (see: http://www.w3fools.com/). Use MDN instead.

Comment: Read more @ http://www.jquerypot.com/how-to-get-substring-from-a-string-with-jquery/

Answer (score 8):

If you want to extract from `a` tag then

```
$('.dep_buttons').text().substr(0,25)
```

---

With the mouseover event,

```
$(this).text($(this).text().substr(0, 25));
```

The above will *extract the text of a tag, then extract again assign it back*.

Comment: I need `$(this)` < operator

Comment: @valkharitonashvili ?? I don't understand your comment

Comment: @valkharitonashvili Though I dont get it, I have fiddle it here http://jsfiddle.net/xvH4X/.  Check this and let me know what is it